# Is it okay to define a totally general swap() function?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, libstdc++, argument-dependent-lookup

The following snippet:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

namespace foo
{
    template <typename T>
    void swap(T& a, T& b)
    {
        T tmp = std::move(a);
        a = std::move(b);
        b = std::move(tmp);
    }

    struct bar { };
}

void baz()
{
    std::unique_ptr<foo::bar> ptr;
    ptr.reset();
}
```

does not compile for me:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -c foo.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5.3.0/memory:81:0,
                 from foo.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::reset(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer) [with _Tp = foo::bar; _Dp = std::default_delete<foo::bar>; std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer = foo::bar*]’:
foo.cpp:20:15:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:342:6: error: call of overloaded ‘swap(foo::bar*&, foo::bar*&)’ is ambiguous
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5.3.0/memory:62,
                 from foo.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/move.h:176:5: note: candidate: void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = foo::bar*]
     swap(_Tp& __a, _Tp& __b)
     ^
foo.cpp:7:10: note: candidate: void foo::swap(T&, T&) [with T = foo::bar*]
     void swap(T& a, T& b)
```

Is this my fault for declaring a `swap()` function so general that it conflicts with `std::swap`?

If so, is there a way to define `foo::swap()` so that it doesn't get hauled in by Koenig lookup?

Comment: Doesn't compile on GCC or Clang, but does compile on MSVC 2015. Another undocumented feature perhaps.

Comment: Damn, those are some good ratios within less than the first hour. +16 upvotes, viewed 77 times, and 4 favorites.

Comment: You should have no reason to define such a general `swap` template in a very specific namespace containing only specific types. Just define a non-template `swap` overload for `foo::bar`. Leave general swapping to `std::swap`, and only provide specific overloads.

Comment: @TemplateRex `foo` is a layer of indirection we use over the standard library.  Many of the platforms we support have incomplete/buggy standard libraries, and on those platforms we will do things like direct `foo::shared_ptr` to `boost::shared_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr`.  One of our platforms has an old `std::swap()` that copies instead of moves, so we provided a replacement in `foo`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes I've updated my answer in response to both your comments.

Comment: Semi-unrelated: Andrew Koenig did not invent Argument Dependent Lookup.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- `unique_ptr<T>` requires `T*` to be a `NullablePointer` [unique.ptr]p3
- `NullablePointer` requires lvalues of `T*` to be `Swappable` [nullablepointer.requirements]p1
- `Swappable` essentially requires `using std::swap; swap(x, y);` to select an overload for `x`, `y` being lvalues of type `T*` [swappable.requirements]p3

In the last step, your type `foo::bar` produces an ambiguity and therefore violates the requirements of `unique_ptr`. libstdc++'s implementation is conforming, although I'd say this is rather surprising.

---

The wording is of course a bit more convoluted, because it is generic.

> *[unique.ptr]p3*
>
> If the type `remove_reference_t<D>::pointer` exists,
>   then `unique_ptr<T, D>::pointer` shall be a synonym for
>   `remove_reference_t<D>::pointer`. Otherwise `unique_ptr<T,
>   D>::pointer` shall be a synonym for `T*`. **The type `unique_ptr<T,
>   D>::pointer` shall satisfy the requirements of `NullablePointer`.**

(emphasis mine)

> *[nullablepointer.requirements]p1*
>
> A `NullablePointer` type is a pointer-like type that supports null
>   values. A type `P` meets the requirements of `NullablePointer` if:
>
> - [...]
> - lvalues of type `P` are swappable (17.6.3.2),
> - [...]
>
> *[swappable.requirements]p2*
>
> An object `t` is swappable with an object `u` if and only if:
>
> - the expressions `swap(t, u)` and `swap(u, t)` are valid when evaluated in the context described below, and
> - [...]
>
> *[swappable.requirements]p3*
>
> The context in which `swap(t, u)` and `swap(u, t)` are evaluated shall
>   ensure that a binary non-member function named “swap” is selected via
>   overload resolution on a candidate set that includes:
>
> - the two `swap` function templates defined in `<utility>` and
> - the lookup set produced by argument-dependent lookup.

Note that for a pointer type `T*`, for purposes of ADL, the associated namespaces and classes are derived from the type `T`. Hence, `foo::bar*` has `foo` as an associated namespace. ADL for `swap(x, y)` where either `x` or `y` is a `foo::bar*` will therefore find `foo::swap`.

Comment: You can find a simpler breakdown [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Swappable) for those that don't speak lawyer. Anyways, while libstdc++ is certainly following the rules here there doesn't seem to be anything that required it to use ADL swap inside reset, considering that libcxx's swap of the deleters is functionally equivalent. I'll chalk this up to quality of implementation.

Comment: @user6253369 it's QoI on the OP's part here. Just don't provide general templates duplicating customization points of STL templates, and especially don't provide your own classes to such STL templates when you do.

Comment: @user6253369 For fancy pointers that actually defined custom swaps, using those may well be more efficient.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is libstdc++'s implementation of `unique_ptr`. This is from their 4.9.2 branch:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/libstdc++/api/a01298_source.html#l00339

```
  338       void
  339       reset(pointer __p = pointer()) noexcept
  340       {
  341     using std::swap;
  342     swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  343     if (__p != pointer())
  344       get_deleter()(__p);
  345       }
```

As you can see, there is an unqualified swap call. Now let's see libcxx (libc++)'s implementation:

https://git.io/vKzhF

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void reset(pointer __p = pointer()) _NOEXCEPT
{
    pointer __tmp = __ptr_.first();
    __ptr_.first() = __p;
    if (__tmp)
        __ptr_.second()(__tmp);
}

_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void swap(unique_ptr& __u) _NOEXCEPT
    {__ptr_.swap(__u.__ptr_);}
```

They don't call `swap` inside `reset` nor do they use an unqualified swap call.

---

[Dyp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36851037/6253369) provides a pretty solid breakdown on why `libstdc++` is conforming but also why your code will break whenever `swap` is required to be called by the standard library. To quote [TemplateRex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/819272/templaterex):

> You should have no reason to define such a general `swap` template in
>   a very specific namespace containing only specific types. Just define
>   a non-template `swap` overload for `foo::bar`. Leave general swapping
>   to `std::swap`, and only provide specific overloads. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850522/is-it-okay-to-define-a-totally-general-swap-function/36851037?noredirect=1#comment61271635_36850522)

As an example, this won't compile:

```
std::vector<foo::bar> v;
std::vector<foo::bar>().swap(v);
```

If you're targeting a platform with an old standard library/GCC (like CentOS), I would recommend using Boost instead of reinventing the wheel to avoid pitfalls like this.

Comment: "I would recommend using Boost instead of reinventing the wheel"  Agreed!  We do this for many things in `foo`.  Unfortunately `boost::swap()` does not do the move-assignments, but just delegates to `std::swap`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes That may be true but I believe that the Boost equivalent of unique_ptr uses move semantics for swap for example.

Comment: Right, but I often want to do `swap(a, b);` where `a` and `b` are of a non-copyable type.  It's a pain to declare an overload for *every* move-only type I define, so I need a `swap()` implementation that moves.

Comment: @TavianBarnes I don't usually give shady advice, but have you considered replacing swap on the shared library level? I believe that's common to do in embedded systems.

Comment: @user6253369 I updated your link to GitHub to the commit directly and ran it through GitHub's link shortener. Feel free to revert the edit if it's the wrong parts.

Answer (score 12):

This technique can be used to avoid `foo::swap()` getting found by ADL:

```
namespace foo
{
    namespace adl_barrier
    {
        template <typename T>
        void swap(T& a, T& b)
        {
            T tmp = std::move(a);
            a = std::move(b);
            b = std::move(tmp);
        }
    }

    using namespace adl_barrier;
}
```

This is how Boost.Range's free-standing `begin()`/`end()` functions are defined.  I tried something similar before asking the question, but did `using adl_barrier::swap;` instead, which doesn't work.

As for whether the snippet in the question should work as-is, I'm not sure.  One complication I can see is that `unique_ptr` can have custom `pointer` types from the `Deleter`, which should be swapped with the usual `using std::swap; swap(a, b);` idiom.  That idiom is clearly broken for `foo::bar*` in the question.

Comment: If it's "totally general", then why don't you just import `std::swap` into `foo` with a using-declaration?

Comment: @dyp `foo::swap()` was written because one of our platforms has a standard library with a deficient `std::swap()` (does copies rather than moves).  I will probably do `using std::swap;` except on that platform.

Comment: btw, I think it's better to ADL-protect your type (i.e. `foo::bar`) instead of your functions (i.e. `foo::swap`), since those are the ones causing the grief, and the number of functions in `namespace foo` is open-ended (someone might add `foo::begin` and `foo::end` someday and then you have new trouble, ADL-protected `foo::bar` guards against that).